# Mockito 1.9.5 throws UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: mockito, stubbing

Can anybody identify why Mockito 1.9.5 is throwing an UnfinishedStubbingException in the 'doesWhatIExpectItTo' test for this code?

```java
public interface Thing {
    String getId();
    boolean isReady();
}

public interface ThingCache {
    Thing getThing(String theId);
}

private Set<String> getThingIdSet(int theSize){
    Set<String> thingIds = new HashSet<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++ ) {
        thingIds.add("thingId-" + i);
    }
    return thingIds;
}

private Thing getANewThing(String theId, boolean isReady) {
    Thing theNewThing = mock(Thing.class);
    when( theNewThing.getId() ).thenReturn(theId);
    when( theNewThing.isReady() ).thenReturn(isReady);
    return theNewThing;
}

@Test
public void doesWhatIExpectItTo() {
    ThingCache theCache = mock(ThingCache.class);

    Set<String> thingIds = getThingIdSet(5);
    for ( String thingId : thingIds ) {
        when( theCache.getThing( thingId ) ).thenReturn( getANewThing(thingId, true) );
    }
}
```

I've tried various alternatives including argument matchers and thenAnswer, run through the SO unfinished stubbing exception questions I was able to find, and I can't seem to find anything to get past this basic problem.

Seems like there is something simple/obvious that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

Problem is that I'm calling getANewThing() in the context of a .thenReturn() call, and I can't start a new .when() call in that context.

Answer is to construct the Thing mock prior to calling .when() on the ThingCache.getThing() method.